# Non user specific path operations?

Tags: file, generics, path, classpath, directory

I am packaging up a program to be sold and I am creating a dll file in a specific folder,
example -
"C:\Users\Jackie\AppData\Roaming\Autodesk\Revit\Addins\2016"

I need to be able to identify that folder on any users machine in the code but i do not know if there is a way of doing this since the username will change etc.

can somebody help me out please?
Thank you
Jack

Comment: C# is the language i am using by the way